# How to detect request coming from Web Browser (but not from API which sets browser "user agent" in header)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, request-headers

I am told to find source of request is browser or not.
I got "user agent" property.

I have searched on Chrome, Firefox and IE and found following strings:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
```

When i initiate request from API or Postman with above mentioned 'User-Agent' in request then how to detect that whether it is some API hitting or browser hitting?

Is there any full proof way to detect whether request comes from Web Browser only? (Not from API, Postman or any source which adds fake User-Agent into it)

Comment: I hope there is no way to establish that.

Comment: [fingerprintjs](https://fingerprintjs.com/open-source/) and [express-fingerprint](https://github.com/yusukeshibata/express-fingerprint). Nothing is "fool proof". The universe will always create a bigger fool if you succeed. I think that is PT Barnum's law.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: It is js library, i need to detect at Java side.

Comment: @fatherazrael It is possible to run something on the user's browser that communicates with your server.

Comment: You are going to the dark side of the force here... The rule is that an API can always pretend to be a Chrome of Firefox browser, because it can forge any header. So the best you can do is to filter genuine API calls that do not try to hide themselves. Long story made short you will bother legitim users just trying to automate some simple tasks, but will not detect advanced or offensive bots. But you are on your own...

Comment: Try use csrf token, or use request fingerprint to detect client touch your webpage before or not